# How can I install a free VPN for Ubuntu in a VM?

Tags: vpn

Just installed Ubuntu on mac through VMware Fusion. Are there any VPNs I can install for free?

Comment: The OpenVPN client is perfectly free, as is the built-in Network Manager's basic VPN support. Whether you can get a free VPN provider is a different matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VPN software is free (like [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source.html)), but the providers worth trusting are not.

You're using a VPN for privacy reasons, so if you're not paying the provider for the service, who is? What interested would someone else have for paying them? The provider could be passing your data onto someone else, which goes against the reason you're using a VPN in the first place.

A Google search will uncover "free vpn" providers quickly. Like anything, do your research to make sure that you're comfortable with who you choose.

I've not given any personal recommendations as I wouldn't use one myself for the reasons I've just mentioned.